# How to check single line if else if else condition in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement

I have three different answers for *holiday_type*

```
holiday_type = Approved
holiday_type = Confirmed
holiday_type = both
```

Python Code:

```
 result = ['confirm','validate'] if holiday_type == 'both' else ['confirm'] if holiday_type == 'Confirmed' else ['validate']
```

Result:

```
['validate']                // Approved
['confirm']                 // Confirmed
['confirm', 'validate']     // both
```

I can't understand how to compile this if else statement: which one first which one second. Can you please explain how to compile this condition flow.

Comment: Why? It is not pythonic.

Comment: Off cause is this pythonic............  but I just want to know flow of this execution. because for loop execution start at the end.

Comment: Hint: `result = ['confirm','validate'] if holiday_type == 'both' else (['confirm'] if holiday_type == 'Confirmed' else ['validate'])` - you can easily see two nested similar statements of `true_val if condition else false_val` form.

Comment: I say execution flow start at the end (right to left) so in this case how is this become nested

Comment: @S͢kyD͢ream: No: there's no simple left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation order here. The evaluation order of the conditional expression `true_expr if condition else false_expr` is `condition` and then one of `true_expr` or `false_expr` is evaluated, as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If th expression is different for different cases, this would be works,

> *expr1* **if** *condition1* **else** *expr2* **if** *condition2* **else** *expr*

For example:

```
>>> a = -5
>>> "negative" if a<0 else "zero" if a==0 else "positive"
'negative'
>>> a = 5
>>> "negative" if a<0 else "zero" if a==0 else "positive"
'positive'
>>> a = 0
>>> "Negative" if a<0 else "zero" if a==0 else "positive"
'zero'
```

Question Example:

```
result = ['confirm','validate'] if holiday_type == 'both' else ['confirm'] if holiday_type == 'Confirmed' else ['validate']
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Readability counts.

```
if holiday_type == 'both':
    result = ['confirm','validate']
elif  holiday_type == 'Confirmed':
    result = ['confirm']
else:
    result = ['validate']
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question (while strange use of ternary operations - is a valid cryt). Sometimes you read other peoples strange code so you need to know how it works exactly before refactoring it.

Answer (score 2):

Statement

```
<expression1> if <condition> else <expression2>
```

first evaluates the `condition`; if it returns `True`, `expression1` will be evaluated to give the result, otherwise `expression2`.

In

```
 result = ['confirm','validate'] if holiday_type == 'both' else ['confirm'] if holiday_type == 'Confirmed' else ['validate']
```

`['confirm'] if holiday_type == 'Confirmed' else ['validate']` is `expression2` and it will be evaluated if `holiday_type == 'both'` is evaluated to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested if-else

generally speaking - 
`x if cond else y` is the normal syntax or a type of statement

now here `x` and `y` can be independent set of statements

You can expand them.

Like in your case `y` is the same statement -> `x if cond else y`
So it becomes

`x if cond else x1 if cond2 else y1`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (['confirm','validate'] if holiday_type == 'both' else
          ['confirm'] if holiday_type == 'Confirmed' else
          ['validate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to borrow from others but give a more generic explanation of how to parse these oneline if statements by translating it to multiple lines.

```
expr1 if condition1 else expr2 if condition2 else expr
```

translates to

```
if condition1:
  expr1
elif condition2:
  expr2
else:
  expr
```

Keep in mind this same style of syntax is used for list comprehensions and other areas of python.